# How to keep the terminal window open after it completes running? (subprocess.Call)

Tags: python, shell, terminal, subprocess, new-window

I have this code in main.py which opens a new terminal with running test.py

`main.py`

```py
import subprocess

subprocess.call(['xterm', '-e', 'python test.py'])
```

`test.py`

```py
print('HELLO')
```

But when the script finishes it directly closes the terminal OR when error occurs it closes the terminal, is there a way to keep the terminal open when script finishes or error occurs? (so I can see whats happening)

Thanks.

Comment: why not open a terminal window yourself and run `python test.py` directly if you just want to look at the output?  or otherwise, why are you running it via xterm... you could capture that output of `subprocess.call(['python', 'test.py'])` in main.py and print it... but even then, why use a subprocess?  why not just import test.py as a module with a function in it and call the function - it will print to the current terminal

Answer (score 0):

You can use only the `input()` at the end of your code but if an error occurs it will still close. So instead you can use this:

```
try:
  import subprocess
  subprocess.call(['xterm', '-e', 'python test.py'])
except BaseException:
  import sys
  print(sys.exc_info()[0])
  import traceback
  print(traceback.format_exc())
finally:
  input()
```